# How can I (de)serialize a class as the type of an inner property?

Tags: c#, json, mongodb, bson

I'm trying to embrace DDD and thus I don't want to just use `Guid` as the ID for all of my objects so I've made a generic type `GuidId<Entity>` to keep some type safety. It looks roughly like this:

```
public class GuidId<T> where T : Entity
{
    public Guid Value { get; private set; }

    public static GuidId<T> Create() => Create(Guid.NewGuid());

    public static implicit operator Guid(GuidId<T> id) => id.Value;
    public static implicit operator GuidId<T>(Guid id) => new GuidId<T>(id);
}
```

The MongoDB serialize currently serializes it like this

```
"aggregateId" : {
    "value" : UUID("77e19ff1-ca08-473e-8108-01945eb8d504")
}
```

but I just want:

```
"aggregateId" : UUID("77e19ff1-ca08-473e-8108-01945eb8d504")
```

I played around with custom serializers for hours to no avail. I feel like there should be an easy way to do this perhaps using the `implicit operator`s I defined? Currently I've just settled for making a separate class for persistence that just uses Guids and I use AutoMapper to map between them.

Additionally I'd like to pass these Guid's around through a RESTful API without having to define an { value: '' }

Comment: FWIW: I'm a fan of good 'ol TT (aka generation) for simple domain specific types. It's to to generate the appropriate types/names (using whatever backing primitives etc.), with the "cost" being a generation stage.. although doesn't address the question at all :)

Comment: Anyhow.. this question is really 'how can I create a completely custom serializer'? If MongdoDB uses Json.NET (for example, eg, leaves it to the client), then the question would be 'how can I create a custom serializer in Json.NET'? (And there are many questions/examples of the latter.)

Comment: Yeah - I guess there is no harm in allowing it to just use the default serialization (if that's what you're saying in your first comment). I'm going to see what I can throw together with a custom Json.NET serializer. Thanks for the pointer - 80% of the struggle is finding the right question to ask :)